# How to upload sourcemaps to sentry using webpack & nextjs?

Tags: webpack, next.js, sentry

Sentry displays minified JavaScript code instead of original one.

Here is report in Sentry:
[image]

Here is my original code:

[image]

I set Sentry's Next.js through wizard with

```
npx @sentry/wizard -i nextjs.
```

Then I had to update **next.config.js** for the needs of the project. This is my **next.config.js**

```
const { withRNV } = require('@rnv/engine-rn-next');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const { withSentryConfig } = require('@sentry/nextjs');

const getPackageVersion = () => {
    const manifest = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './package.json'), 'utf8'));
    return manifest.version;
};

const config = {
    compress: false,
    webpack: (cfg, { isServer }) => {
        if (!isServer) cfg.resolve.alias['@sentry/node'] = '@sentry/browser';
        cfg.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 100000,
                    name: '[name].[ext]',
                },
            },
        });
        return cfg;
    },
    typescript: {
        ignoreBuildErrors: true,
    },
    publicRuntimeConfig: {
        deployEnv: process.env.DEPLOY_ENV || 'Development',
        customScripts: [],
    },

    images: {
        loader: 'akamai',
        path: '',
    },
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/(.*)',
                headers: [
                    {
                        key: 'X-Application-Version',
                        value: getPackageVersion(),
                    },
                    {
                        key: 'access-control-allow-origin',
                        value: '*',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ];
    },
    experimental: {
        outputStandalone: true,
    },
};

module.exports = withSentryConfig(
    withRNV(config, {
        enableNextCss: false,
        enableOptimizedImages: true,
    })
);
```

I am using:

```
"next": "12.0.9",
"@sentry/nextjs": "7.20.0",
```

What can be root cause of wrong Sentry report?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can try to use `sentry-webpack-plugin` to upload sourcemaps to your sentry server: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin#cli-configuration

Comment: I tried, but too many errors while running `yarn webpack`.